# Show $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-field on $\mathcal X$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

[image]

The conditions are:

1. $\mathcal X, \emptyset\in\mathcal {A\cap B}$ because they are in each of the sets, so they are in both of them
2. $C\in\mathcal A\cap B\Rightarrow C\in \mathcal A$ and $C\in\mathcal B\Rightarrow C^c\in\mathcal A$ and $C^c\in\mathcal B\Rightarrow C^c\in\mathcal {A\cap B}$
3. $C_1,C_2,\dots \in\mathcal {A\cap B}\Rightarrow C_1,C_2,\dots \in\mathcal A$ and $C_1,C_2,\dots \in\mathcal B\Rightarrow\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n\in\mathcal A$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n\in\mathcal B\Rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n\in\mathcal {A\cap B}$

Is it right? And is writing out the middle two steps in 2. and 3. necessary? I'm guessing they are necessary but if you're experienced enough you might not need them.

Comment: All your steps look good.

Comment: Yes, write out the extra steps whenever you need to.  If you are experienced enough, and you reader is also experienced enough, then you might not need them.  So keep in mind what type of reader you are trying to reach.